# Couldn't the "Punishment fit the crime?"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

As a new user on Stack Overflow, we probably all experienced a "bad first question" type of post. The flags, the downvotes, the close votes. The "New Contributor" system works okay, but it doesn't solve the initial problem.

When your question gets closed, all you see is a little yellow box. Well, I think the punishment should fit the crime:

- **Duplicate:** Require the user to open and read the top 3 similar questions before asking a question for 3 days
- **Low Quality:** Required to edit post within 3 days or automatically closed/deleted/on hold
- **Unclear/Too broad/Off Topic:** User required to reread certain articles about what is on topic (From help center)

This system would help to make the user realize *what* they did wrong, *how* to fix it, and *why* they should do it the right way. I assume there is some reason this has not been done, so can someone please enlighten me to why?

Comment: There's no practical way for SO to require any of its users to do anything at all.

Comment: Intent is good, but, as a new user, you get a *lot* of information placed in front of you.  Even a checkbox or two that says, "Yes, I read this and I agree".  Users won't read what they don't want to.  All they'll do is abandon the question/account, and ask it again.

Comment: For '*Require the user to open and read the top 3 similar questions before asking a question for 3 days*' and '*User required to reread certain articles about what is on topic (From help center)*' - I'm not sure about others, but I got the tour badge for scrolling, not reading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Duplicate:** Require the user to open and read the top 3 similar questions before asking a question for 3 days

Duplicates aren't always a bad thing.

> **Low Quality:** Required to edit post within 3 days or automatically closed/deleted/on hold

The entire point of the "on hold" verbiage is to give the asker a grace period of 5 days to edit their question before it gets relabeled as "closed" under the assumption that they have chosen to abandon their question instead. Also low quality != off-topic. Two separate issues.

> **Unclear/Too broad/Off Topic:** User required to reread certain articles about what is on topic (From help center)

If a user didn't read how-to-ask the first time, it's unlikely trying again to make them read it will work.

Also, I appreciate that this may be a language barrier thing, but calling these issues "crimes" is not only quite the stretch, but also directly counter to the goal of the new contributor indicator.

Comment: Isn't "punishment to fit the crime" also a saying? Or am I remembering wrong?

Comment: @Epodax: I suppose it is, with "crime" being just as metaphorical here as it is in "partners in crime".

Comment: It is a metaphor, but a loaded one. These aren't crimes, nor are corrective actions meant to be punishment. Poor choice of words, imo.